# Windows Mobile Cellular Emulator on x64

Tags: windows-mobile, emulation

is there any fix for running windows mobile cellular emulator in a x64 windows 7 ?

I'm not sure if it is about x64 though. I am getting the error

There are not seven pairs of XPVCOM in system.

Comment: Is this for Windows Phone7 or Windows Mobile 6 or earlier

Answer (score 0):

My [latest info (2008)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/microsoftdeviceemu/thread/ae6958d3-7d08-492e-9b94-5dc6edb50ec5/) is that it does not work on x64 systems. 
And in a [German MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/windows_mobilede/thread/a993123b-0dd2-4265-8238-5632bd37227c/) it looks like it probably never will.

They suggest the same thing I'd try out: Run it in a Virtual Machine. Not exactly comfortable but still better than nothing.